# Sum of values for a given week

Tags: excel, formula

I have a sheet that is tracking the cost of transactions ordered by date. This is how it looks so far:

[image: (http://imgur.com/TJxzKyi)]

I would now like to add another column that has the Weekly Totals (Monday - Sunday) printed in the last row for each Sunday. How can this be done?

I have tried this formula so far:

`=IF(AND(WEEKDAY(A2)=0,A2<>A3),SUMIF(A:A,AND(<=A1>=A1-6),B:B))`

but it is the use of two criteria in the SUMIF that has me lost.

Comment: use SUMIFS() not SUMIF()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the following formula is what you need:

> =IF(AND(WEEKDAY(A2)=1,A2<>A3),SUMIFS(B:B,A:A,">="&(A2-6),A:A,"<="&A2),"")

Note that the `SUMIFS` function is used to handle the multiple IFs, as opposed to the `SUMIF` function.

The `IF` function uses the `AND` function to test two conditions:

1. Is the `WEEKDAY` number equal to 1? (e.g., is this row for a Sunday?)
2. And is the current row's date non-equal to the next row's date? (e.g., is this the last row for the date?)

If either of the above are false, then the formula returns an empty string, "".  If both of the above are true, then it sums the values in column B if the following two conditions are both met:

1. The value in column A is greater than or equal to the value of the current date minus 6 days.
2. The value in column A is less than or equal to the value of the current date.

Comment: This works perfectly, there is just one more adjustment I have realised I now need - is there anyway to adjust this formula so that it only prints the total on the last row of a Sunday if this row is above the last non-empty row of another column (this other column has another formula with an IF([criteria],[Print something],"") - so I am looking for the last row where the TRUE part of this IF is executed)?

Comment: Yes, I think (if I understand correctly). You can just put your logic from the other column as a new IF at the beginning, something like: `=IF([same criteria as other column],IF(AND(WEEKDAY(A2)=1,A2<>A3),SUMIFS(B:B,A:A,">="&(A2-6),A:A,"<="&A2),""),"")`